# What does C++ standard mean by "cast expression in a delete expression shall be evaluated once"?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, delete-operator

I am going through n3337 and not able to understand what the standard means by following sentence in **[expr.delete]**:

> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.delete#4) The cast-expression in a delete-expression shall be evaluated exactly once.

Could someone explain what would be the consequence had the above statement not been present?
Please provide contrasting examples to explain it.